# Where is the lldb executable vscode uses?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, lldb

I'm having difficulty with debugging rust in vscode (It can't evaluate any expressions involving functions).
I noticed that I don't have lldb installed (Ubuntu 20.04), but the debugger is still running. Where is it finding the lldb executable? Can I change the path?

Comment: Start up a debug session, then in terminal do: `ps -jwwx | grep lldb`.  That should show you the lldb-vscode instance that vscode is using.  If vscode launched it by relative path the full path might not show up in the command.  In that case, you can take the PID and ask what open files it has.  That should give you the full path to the binary as well.  But I couldn't find the two error strings you quoted in your related bug in the lldb sources, so you may be running something other than lldb...

Comment: If you are using the `vscode-lldb` extension, the binaries are in the extension folder. I don't know how to solve the functions issues, I'm not sure if it's already implemented for Rust.