# vscode-lldb doesn't evaluate rust expressions

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, expression, lldb

When debugging my code in vscode I noticed that it can't seem to find any functions I call. I tried adding to `main.rs`:

```
pub fn factorial(n: usize) -> usize {
    if n == 0 {
        1
    } else {
        n * factorial(n - 1)
    }
}
```

then I set a breakpoint at the start of the program and typed in the Debug Console

`p factorial(5)`

but I just get

`error: could not find item`.

If I write

`p crate::factorial(5)`

I get `error: could not find decl "factorial"`

What's the correct way to do it? I can't find any examples anywhere.

Comment: Unrelated, but assuming this subsequent question implies you found a solution to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65542559/where-is-the-lldb-executable-vscode-uses), then you could post the answer, for future people having the same issue :)

Comment: Nope. I just decided to go ahead and post my follow-up question anyway. I was hoping if I got a quick answer to the previous one I could make this one not about vscode, but since I didn't I didn't bother